# json library for java 1.4

Tags: java, json, java1.4

I'm using JCAPS 5.1.3 and only have Java 1.4 and need to handle with Json data. Unfortunately all libraries I've found use Java 1.5 and above. 
[I just found lots of new implementations in this thread here, but which one works with 1.4.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/338586/2186724)

**Is there a stable and simple version to use with Java 1.4?**

Comment: http://www.json.org/java/

Comment: I really recommend you to update to a newer Java version. A big advantage of Java is backward compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

[Xstream](http://x-stream.github.io/) 1.2.2 supports Java 1.4. It's the only library I've found that supports Java 1.4. It definitely has its warts though.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to use Retroweaver to make the jar compatible with Java 1.4:

http://retroweaver.sourceforge.net

Answer (score 1):

You can use [my json library](https://gitlab.com/MarianoLEANCE/json-legacy-tools). It supports marshalling and unmarshalling to classes (with some restrictions) and parsing.

Marshalling:

```
Knight knight = new Knight();

knight.name = "Lancelot";
knight.weapon = new Weapon();
knight.weapon.metal = "true silver";
knight.weapon.name = "piercer";
knight.rank = 2;
knight.titles = new String[] { "noble", "round table member" };

Land goldshire = new Land();
goldshire.name = "GoldShire";
goldshire.surface = 45532.3;
Land direwood = new Land();
direwood.name = "Direwood";
direwood.surface = 472;
knight.lands = new Land[] { goldshire, direwood };

System.out.println("Test 1 : marshall simple class:");
String generated = JsonFactory.marshal(knight).toString();
```

Unmarshalling:

```
Knight knight = (Knight) JsonFactory.unmarshal(new FileTools().readFile("UnmarshallingTest1.json"), Knight.class);
```

Comment: Wow, you really dug up this post from over 2 years ago